# Widget onclick pending intent doesn't fire when using flag FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I've got a simple widget that displays a random number. When tapped it refreshes and displays another random number. This is the code for the onUpdate method of the AppWidgetProvider

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        int number = new Random().nextInt(100);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_exchange);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_textview, String.valueOf(number));

        // Register an onClickListener
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExchangeWidgetProvider.class);

        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] {widgetId} );

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_textview, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

With this the widget does its first update when placed but then doesn't update again when clicked. If i just change the pending intent line from:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, widgetId, intent, 0);
```

i.e. only thing that changed was the last parameter is now '0'

it now works as expected and clicking on it causes it to display a new random number.

How come this works, but it doesn't work when it has the FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag?

Answer (score 0):

Note the documentation from PendingIntent:

```
/**
 * Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists,
 * then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new
 * Intent. For use with {@link #getActivity}, {@link #getBroadcast}, and
 * {@link #getService}. <p>This can be used if you are creating intents where only the
 * extras change, and don't care that any entities that received your
 * previous PendingIntent will be able to launch it with your new
 * extras even if they are not explicitly given to it.
 */
public static final int FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT = 1<<27;
```

This means that setting `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` doesn't mean update the broadcast listener, but update the pending intent if it exists. In your case it doesn't exist so this gets ignored.